# How to detect UISearchBar is containing blank spaces only

Tags: iphone

How to detect if UISearchBar contains only blank spaces not any other character or string and replace it with @""?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can trim the string with a character set containing whitespace using the NSString [stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:) message (using the [whitespaceCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceCharacterSet)):

```
NSString * searchString = [searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if (![searchString length])
   // return ... search bar was just whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check as

```
 [yourSearchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""] && [searchBar.text length] ==0){
   // Blank Space in searchbar

else{
 // Do Search
}
```

Comment: Blank spaces takes length equal to the number of times you tap space bar. I tried this. Well thanks!

Comment: Yes. What exactly you want ? Do you want to check whether user just enter spaces only ?

Comment: yes I already mentioned it in my question. Any ways, I found the solution above :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you detect and replace it: (assuming the `UISearchField` is called `searchBar`)

```
NSString*replacement;

if ([searchBar.text isEqualToString:@" "])
{
    replacement = [NSString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}

searchBar.text = replacement;
```

Have a look in the Apple Documentation for [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for more.

Edit:

If you have more than once space, do this:

```
    NSString *s = [someString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                        withString:@""
                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])
                  ];

    searchBar.text = s;
```

Comment: searchBar.text could be @" ", or @"    ", or @"         ", it can go longer so this condition will not help

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isEqualToString` method of [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` to trim the character from NSString.

```
- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set
```

Use as below.

```
NSString* myString = mySearchBar.text
myString = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thanks man, You are right but I already accepted the answer of RedBlueThing, he told me first. well thanks!

Comment: @Harsh Mehrotra : No issue dude, That's great you have accept the answer which help you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  if you are using @"" or length already to control say a button then this version really does detect the whitespace,  if a space has been entered...

```
if([activeField.text isEqualToString:@" "] && [activeField.text length] ==1){
    // Blank Space in searchbar
{
    // an alert example


}
```

Comment: This will detect 1 whitespace and I made it fire when the keyboard was dismissed then I was sure the user had finished and could warn them before they moved on, while at the same time not interfering with all the other code.